# how can I get mail app's notification in iOS from my own app?

Tags: ios, email, notifications

I want to get notification of mail app that apple created from my app that I will create.
Is it possible that getting information of another app or built-in app?

Please, Let me Know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't possible. In iOS, your app is sandboxed and there is no interapplication communication.

Comment: Relevant Meta discussion: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261168/is-this-is-not-possible-an-acceptable-answer

Comment: @AndrewMedico I don't think that's terribly relevant, actually. It's just a matter of kindness vs. nastiness. The question was a reasonable one and I don't see why I should be taken to task for kindly giving a reasonable answer. If this were OS X (desktop), such a notification might be possible, or IAC could be used. But on iOS that isn't possible. That's a nontrivial, interesting fact, and the OP deserves to be told it.

Comment: an app can access canlendar, reminder, photo.. so i thought an app can access also mail by accepting permission.

Comment: An app can send mail, and can even put up some interface that looks like the mail composition interface of the Mail app. But it cannot interact with the actual Mail _app_, which is what you asked. — Similarly, an app can access the calendar _data_, and can even display some interface that looks like the Calendar app. But it cannot interact with the actual Calendar _app_.

Comment: And there is no access to the user's mail storage, which seems to be what you're asking for.